# Excel: Change the color of the cell based on a threshold reached and matching to a string

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, conditional-statements, vlookup

| Activity | Employee | Week of May 17 | Week of May 24 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Inbox | Alice | 3 | 4 |
| Inbox | Jane | 5 | 8 |
| Alpha Project | Alice | 10 | 3 |
| Beta Project | Francis | 7 | 5 |
| Chi Project | Jane | 4 | 3 |

I've attempted to use conditional formatting, arrays & Vlookups and unable to cleanly get the following end result.

The End result is to flag anybody **working > 10 hours for a given week**.

Table is above.

End result should change the color of a cell titled "Alice" outside of this table because Alice worked 13 hours during Week of May 17.

End result should change the color of a cell titled "Jane" outside of this table because Jane worked 11 hours during Week of May 24.

Francis worked 10 hours or below, so no action is needed.

Any help on this is much appreciated --

Comment: Can you give the condition(s) you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a condition with the following formula:

```
=SUMIF(B2:B6,F2,C2:C6)>10
```

Where `B2:B6` is the column of Employee names, `F2` is the cell you want coloured, and `C2:C6` is the column of the May 17th week

Comment: This worked great ... Thank you! @cybernetic.nomad

Comment: Is there another way to this using arrays?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You could edit your question or ask another with more details